# Is it possible to non-programmatically merge config objects that are at different hierarchical levels?

Tags: java, configuration, akka, typesafe-config

I'm using TypeSafe Config. Imagine I want to have application wide defaults for resilience patterns but override them specifically at lower config level. I would prefer to have a generic solution instead of manually coding the config creation for each and every stream. Please see example configs:

application.conf

```
application {
  streams {
    retry {
      attempts = 100
      poll-interval = 5s
      minBackoff = 200 ms
      maxBackoff = 2s
      randomFactor = 0.25
    }
  }
}
```

service1.conf

```
application {
  streams {
    stream1 {
      retry {
        attempts = 2
      }
    }
    stream2 {
      retry {
        poll-interval = 5s
      }
    }
  }
```

**Is there a way to non-programmatically merge these configs? Use the defaults from application.conf and override if the value exists in the lower level?**

**What's the best practice here?**

I can't use:

```java
var defaultConf = ConfigFactory.load("application.conf");
var conf = ConfigFactory.load("service1.conf").withFallback(defaultConf);
```

Because the configs are not at the same hierarchical level.

Comment: Did you consider to use standard, ie built-in, principle of sharing defaults via a `reference.conf`? If yes, please update your question why it doesn't suit you

Comment: I don't see how to handle hierarchy in that way, do you have an example? Like a parent node with config that child nodes can overwrite or use the default from the parent

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76635447/4803842)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I agree with Ivan and the link to [his other answer regarding reference configs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76635447/4803842). (Or any type of base config.)

The part that I think you are missing is the "hierarchy". You can do that, in a non-programmatic way, using inheritance. Here is the docs: https://github.com/lightbend/config#inheritance . You can have a generic config in your reference and then inherit and override in your hierarchy. The docs have an example very similar to yours.

The gist would be to reference the generic config with something like:

```
application.streams.stream1 = ${application.streams}
application.streams.stream1.retry.attempts = 2

application.streams.stream2 = ${application.streams}
application.streams.stream2.retry.poll-interval = 5s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the part of hierarchy that I was missing. It might not be ideal but at least I won't have to repeat the whole parent structure in all the child configs.